# Commands terminated with the same char

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I fix the follow line:

```
for line in $(cat /root/files_to_search); do find /opt/ -iname $line -exec rm {} >> files_founded.txt ; done
```

The problem is that the commands of `for` and `-exec` end with a semicolon, the `for` command has this statement

```
for i in something; do command ; done (do terminate with ;)
```

and `find` statment with `-exec`

```
find /path/ -name somestring -exec command \; (-exec also finish with ;)
```

Comment: You escape the semicolon, as you have done in the final line, so that it is treated as a literal argument to the `-exec` primary rather than a shell command terminator. That said, it is incorrect to use a `for` loop to iterate over a file's contents in this fashion.

Comment: As you said, I do "/;;" and works, but why you say that is incorrect to use for in this case?

Comment: @JoaoVitorino: see [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and [BashFAQ #1—How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: thanks @gniourf_gniourf, I thought the choice between for and while as a question of good practice only. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to use `-exec echo {}` since that is default action in `find`. You can use this for loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    find /opt/ -iname "$line"
done < /root/files_to_search >> files_founded.txt
```

There is no need to use `for line in $(cat ...)` either as you can read from the input using `< file`

[See BASH FAQ on reading a file line by line](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

If you must use `-exec` in `find` then use:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    find /opt/ -iname "$line" -exec rm {} \;
done < /root/files_to_search >> files_founded.txt
```

Comment: Ok, was a broad example, but if was -exec rm -r {} or something different than echo? I edited the question to correct the example.

Comment: Works, what chepner say work too, but as gniourf_gniourf tha really make understand why use ´while´ and no ´for´.